# How do you change the endpoint of a service reference without regenerating the client code?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

We have a 3rd party SOAP API we're integrating with. We've done development against the development version of this API. Now we want to switch over to the production version. How do we do this without regenerating the entire service reference against the new endpoint url? In a perfect world, we would just be able to change a path in a config file to point to the new endpoint but that doesn't seem to work due to namespaces issues.

When changing the endpoint address in the config (or programmatically), this error occurs at runtime:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://foo.bar.com/DEVWebService/AuthenticateUser. 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

I believe this is because the auto-generated reference class has those SOAP Actions baked in:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://foo.bar.com/DEVWebService/AuthenticateUser", ReplyAction="*")]
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
System.Data.DataSet AuthenticateUser(string strSecurityKey, string strUsername, string strPassword);
```

What is the best way to easily change the endpoint url via a configuration instead of rebuilding all of the code for the service reference?